# What constitutes a 'safe route' for the Fear spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, fear

The description of the [*fear*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fear) spell says:

> While frightened by this spell, a creature must take the Dash action and move away from you **by the safest available route** on each of its turns, unless there is nowhere to move.

Imagine these scenarios, which all happen in a narrow corridor with the caster in front of you:

1. Behind you is a deep pit of 10 feet wide. You could jump, but if you
   fail your Athletics check, you'll fall into the pit and die.
2. Same as 1, except you won't die but take a lot of damage.
3. Same as 1, except you have a fear of heights.
4. Behind you is a flaming corridor, which deals damage for every 5
   feet you move.

Those represent uncertain situations where it might or might not be safe to cross the escape route. The fourth scenario represents a certain situation where you will take damage, but it won't necessarily kill you, if you try to escape using that route.

**What is the threshold of 'safe' in the *fear* spell description?** Must the victim run through the route even if there is certain danger? What if the danger is highly probable, but not certain? Can those routes be considered the "safest available route"?

Comment: An important factor is how far you are from the pit when the spell is cast.  If you are standing at the edge then you cannot back away to get a running start because it would move you closer to the caster.  A very different situation than i f you are 15 feet away from the pit when the spell is cast, causing you to dash 15 feet and then choosing between stopping short or attempting the jump.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The victim has to take the "safest available", even if it is not "safe"

In all the circumstances you describe, none of the routes are safe but they are each the "safest available". If the victim has a choice between 2 or more unsafe routes I would let the victim use their own judgement as to which was the "safest available".

Only if there is "nowhere to move" - i.e. every possible route brings the victim closer to "you" - can the victim stand still.

Comment: Linked from other question brought me here. I'd like an answer which would take an opinion on if suicidal route is an available route. Like, does casting Fear near a cliff and towards the cliff cause everybody affected to commit suicide by jumping down to their death?

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir I've ruled at my table that obvious instant death counts as having nowhere to go, but there's some character's-brain interpretation there, and it very rarely comes up anyway.

Answer (score 13):

### "Safest" doesn't mean "safe"

The target has to take the saf**est** route, which doesn't mean only routes that are totally safe. If the safest route is still life-threatening, they'll do it, because that's what *fear* does. Attempting risky maneuvers to escape from the source of their fear is entirely within the purview of the spell, even if the path is itself terrifying, dangerous, or irrational. The spell overrides normal concerns.

It really almost never comes up, though. It's very rare that the situation prevents all movement except in a damaging or actually suicidal direction.

### But "safest" and "nowhere" are up to DM interpretation

At my table, I have ruled in the past that obvious instant death (such as going over the side of a flying airship) is functionally impassible and counts as having "nowhere to move". But most cliffs are at least theoretically climbable, so the target could try to descend that way instead of just leaping to its doom.

However, it has to be *instant* death. Jumping off a ship in the middle of the ocean is definitely deadly *in the long term* for most land-dwellers, but it isn't *immediately* fatal, so a creature under the effects of *fear* would be willing to jump in the ocean and swim away with no clear destination, at least until the spell ended.

There's a certain amount of judgement call in terms of whether a given target *thinks* a particular action is instantly deadly or not, though, and thus whether or not it's a valid path. A high level barbarian might look at a five-story drop and think, "I can totally tank that" where a low level sorcerer might well consider that same drop to be instant death (unless he happens to know *featherfall*). I don't think it's useful to try to create a list of what does or doesn't count as 'instantly deadly' ahead of time, because it's very difficult to predict all the options that will be available to any given character in any given case.